Does a Homothetic Function with Respect to Consumption and Hours Worked Satisfy Certain Conditions in Fiscal Policy Models?
Proposition 3: If the utility function is homothetic with respect to consumption and hours worked, then the steady-state capital tax is zero.
Proof: This class of preference satisfies:
\begin{equation}\tag{42}\label{42}
c^{i}_{t}U_{cc^i_t}+l^i_{t}U_{lc^i_t}=AU_{c^i_t}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{43}\label{43}
l^i_tU_{ll^i_t}+c^i_tU_{cl^i_t}=BU_{l^i_t}
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are different constant...
My Question
The above is part of the article ''Optimal Fiscal Policy in Overlapping Generations Models'' (Garriga 2019). I would like to understand why he states equations \eqref{42} and \eqref{43}.
My Attempt
Affirmation: If $U(c,l)$  is a homothetic function, it doesn't necessarily hold \eqref{42} and \eqref{43}.
Proof: Consider the function $f(x,y)=e^{x+y}$. This function is a homothetic.
$\bullet$ If $ x+y=g(x,y) $, and $ f(x,y)=e^{g(x,y)} $,
$\bullet$ $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}=e^g > 0 $, so $ f $ is increasing in $ g $.
$\bullet$ On the other hand, $g(\lambda x, \lambda y)=\lambda x + \lambda y=\lambda g(x,y) $, so $g$ is homogeneous of degree 1.
Therefore, it is verified that $ f(x,y)=e^{x+y} $ is homothetic.
Let's check if the function $ f(x,y) = e^{x+y} $ satisfies equation \eqref{42}.
$\bullet$ $ f_x = f_y = f_{xx} = f_{yx} = e^{x+y} $.
$\bullet$ Substituting into equation \eqref{42}, we get:
$ xe^{x+y} + ye^{x+y} = (x+y)e^{x+y} $
This result indicates that a homothetic function does not necessarily satisfy equation \eqref{42}.

You are correct. The condition is true for homogeneous functions but not for homothetic ones.
If $U$ is homogeneous of degree $\alpha$ then $U_c$ and $U_\ell$ are homogeneous of degree $\alpha - 1$.
The equations (42) and (43) are obtained applying Euler's theorem to these two functions.
